# Is it possible to programmatically analyze facebook trade groups?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to programmatically analyze facebook trade groups? If yes, could you point me to a tutorial?

Edit: OK, seems like it's illegal per Facebook Terms of Service. I guess this makes the question irrelevant: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: There is no API for it and as you found scraping is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

As Wizkid mentioned, facebook does not provide an api for fetching other people's facebook page content.

**You can access plenty of information about your own Facebook Page using the Graph API, but not pages you dont have permissions on.**

Programmatically accessing the page content of pages outside the graph api violates the facebook TOS, which will result in banning.